# VLJC stop webcam stream

Tags: java, webcam

I'm trying to stream my web camera using VLJC, but how can I stop webcam stream?, This is my code to start webcam :

```
private static void VCVideo() {

    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayerForVC = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayerForDRV = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayerForVC.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(canvasMainCamera_VC));

    mediaPlayerForVC.playMedia(CAM_VC_ADDRESS);
}
```

`mediaPlayerForVC.stop()`  give me an Exception error. I also cannot take snapshot using  `mediaPlayerForVC.saveSnapshot(file)`. It gave me an Exception error too. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What error do you get? Explain that in your question, otherwise it will be hard to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: i only have this : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at gui.JMainFrame.actionPerformed(JMainFrame.java:654), where line 654 is mediaPlayerForVC.stop()

Comment: check if mediaPlayerForVC is null at that point...